# Try-with-resources scope of resource

Tags: java, eclipse, scope, java-7

In the *`try`-with-resources* construct of **Java 7**, I can declare a resource in the `try` statement, and it will be closed automatically when it goes out of scope.

However, I don't find any indication of the **scope of the resource** made available. Specifically, is it available in the `catch`/`finally` blocks of the try block where it is declared?

I tried the following in **Eclipse Kepler**, but it's giving a mixed impression:

Resource variable is made available by *Content Assist (Code Completion)*:

[image: Content Assist suggests resource]

*Quick Fix* suggests changing to resource variable, but this recursively produces the same problem it's trying to fix:

[image: Redundant suggestion in Quick Fix]

I would like to know what the **correct scope limitation** is, before raising a bug in the *Eclipse Bug Tracker*.

Comment: Nambari, Sotirios, rocketboy, I can't accept one answer right now because all are good in their own terms. I will leave it for votes for a while before deciding on the best. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This syntax is called ***Extended try-with-resources***

As per [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3):

```
try ResourceSpecification
    Block
Catchesopt
Finallyopt
```

Will be translated to:

```
try {
    try ResourceSpecification
        Block
}
Catchesopt
Finallyopt
```

So, in your example, your resource will be limited to inner try block, so not available for outer `try/catch/finally`.

**EDIT:**

> my question does not have nested try blocks

By explicitly adding catch/finally block in your code, you are introducing nested try blocks.

Comment: Sorry, my question does not have nested `try` blocks. Can I know the relevance of your answer?

Comment: @ADTC: Please refer language specification link in answer. Refer section 14.20.3.2.

Answer (score 8):

## **Update from 2017 after Java 9 release**

Now with `Java 9` we have more syntactic sugar and we can have a resource declared outside the `try-catch` block but still handled properly. That's why with **Java 9 the Try-With-Resources has been improved** introducing a new syntax:

```
InputStream stream = new MyInputStream(...)
try (stream) {
   // do something with stream being sure that is going to be closed at the end
} catch(IOException e) {
   // the resource (in this case, the stream) has been closed - see the end
}
```

*Note that this syntax will result in a compile time error for Java version 8 or minor*

This is more "natural" way of writing even though in most use cases we don't need the resource outside the scope of the try block.
The only  restriction is that the reader variable should be effectively final or just final.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), using `try with resources`, it mentions 'in a try-with-resources statement, any catch or finally block is run after the resources declared have been closed'.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Nambari's answer:

> A try-with-resources statement can have catch and finally blocks just
>   like an ordinary try statement. In a try-with-resources statement, any
>   catch or finally block is run after the resources declared have been
>   closed.

That pretty much explains the behaviour, your resource goes out of scope in your explicit catch/finally block.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: May I know the statement in your reference that mentions the same thing as your blockquote?

Comment: Its under _Note_ on the given reference page.

Comment: Oh yea, sorry.. Chrome search hiccup! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The correct scope limitation is within the declaration part `(...)` and the actual `try` block.

The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) states

> The scope of a variable declared in the ResourceSpecification of a
>   try-with-resources statement (§14.20.3) is from the declaration
>   rightward over the remainder of the ResourceSpecification and the
>   entire try block associated with the try-with-resources statement.

So from the point it is declared in the ResourceSpecification `(...)` of the `try` onwards until the final closing `}` bracket of the `try` `Block`.

```
TryWithResourcesStatement:
    try ResourceSpecification Block Catchesopt Finallyopt

ResourceSpecification:
    ( Resources ;opt )

Resources:
    Resource
    Resource ; Resources

Resource:
    VariableModifiersopt Type VariableDeclaratorId = Expression
```

Comment: Do you mean **the resource variable** is not supposed to be available in catch/finally blocks? Please elaborate your answer. It is currently as vague as the Java 7 documentation..

Comment: @ADTC Only available in the `try` block means only until `try (..) {}` ends. Not in `catch`, not in `finally`

Comment: @ADTC The JLS has a drawing for us, see my edit. It is contained within `ResourceSpecification` and `Block`. the Java 7 documentation is pretty explicit.

Comment: Thank you. I guess this means I can file a bug with Eclipse that the _Code Completion_ **must not** make the resource available in `catch`/`finally` blocks. Right?

Comment: @ADTC Sure, it looks like it.