# Why is it possible to use a Closed object outside of its try-with-resources scope?

Tags: java, httpclient, java-7, try-with-resources

[I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691352/try-with-resources-scope-of-resource) that resources initialized in a try-with-resources block are only in scope for the duration of the block.

If that's the case, then how does this code seem to get around that?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Main main = new Main();

        try {
            final char[] buffer = new char[10];
            StringReader stringReader = main.testStream();
            System.out.println(stringReader.read(buffer, 0, 10));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("expected IOException caught here"); 
        }

        try {
            HttpResponse response = main.tryResponse();
            response.getEntity();
            System.out.println("should not reach this line if response is out of scope");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("why no IOException here?");
        }
    }

    StringReader tryStream() throws IOException {
        try (StringReader reader = new StringReader("string")) {
            return reader;
        }
    }

    HttpResponse tryResponse() throws IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request)) {
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

What are java best practices concerning situations like this?

Comment: This code should . . . not work. Does it really? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947755/try-with-resources-and-return-statements-in-java

Comment: Well, you'll get a closed `Closeable` back. Is that different than what you thought will happen?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes, it was.  In the case of an `InputStream`, accessing a closed stream throws an exception.  Are there other examples of `Closeable` objects that can be used after they are closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope is a **compile time** concept that governs where names in source code can be used. From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)

> The scope of a declaration is the region of the program within which
>   the entity declared by the declaration can be referred to using a
>   simple name, provided it is visible (§6.4.1).

In other words, it doesn't apply to objects (which is a runtime concept), only to the variables (and other named elements) that refer to them.

For your example (assume without the `return`), it wouldn't compile if you tried to use the variable `response` outside the `try` block:

```
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request)) {    
} 
System.out.println(response); // nope, compilation error
```

A `return` statement evaluates the expression it's given (a variable in this case), resolves a value (a reference to a `CloseableHttpResponse` object), copies that value, and returns it, popping the current method stack frame from the stack and returning execution to the invoking method.

With your `try-with-resources` statement, the actual `return` action is preceded by a `finally` block which invokes `close()` on the object referenced by the `response` variable. Presumably, this puts the object in some unusable state. You will probably get run-time exceptions depending on how you then use it (ie. in the method receiving the `return` value).

Comment: I see, so the terminology is wrong, but more generally, the answer to the question is:  there is no spec concerning the state or behavior of closed objects other than that they be closed according the `Closeable` contract?

Comment: @jordanpg That's right. `Closeable` is just an interface. `try-with-resources` is just a [fancy `try-catch-finally`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) that invokes `close` (which is just a method). There are `Closeable` implementations whose `close` methods are no-ops, `ByteArrayInputStream` for example.

Comment: @jordanpg Basically, you should defer to the javadoc (or the implementation if the rest of the documentation is bad) of the type you're using to know what to expect.